# Memory allocation for linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, memory-management

I am new to C and am writing a basic program to calculate the arithmetic sum of two numbers stored in a linked list.

My main question is idiomatic memory management in C. The program below allocates a new linked list node, but does not deallocate it. What is a good way to do so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct SinglyLinkedListInt {
  int value;
  struct SinglyLinkedListInt *next;
} SinglyLinkedListInt;

SinglyLinkedListInt *add_two_numbers(SinglyLinkedListInt *l1, SinglyLinkedListInt *l2) {
  SinglyLinkedListInt root = { .value = 0, .next = NULL };
  SinglyLinkedListInt *current = &root;

  int carry = 0;
  while (l1 || l2 || carry) {
    int a = l1 ? l1->value : 0;
    int b = l2 ? l2->value : 0;
    int value = carry + a + b;

    SinglyLinkedListInt *next = malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedListInt));
    next->value = value % 10;
    next->next = NULL;
    current->next = next;

    carry = value / 10;
    l1 = l1 ? l1->next : NULL;
    l2 = l2 ? l2->next : NULL;
    current = current->next;
  }

  return root.next;
}

int main() {
  SinglyLinkedListInt l13 = { .value = 3, .next = NULL };
  SinglyLinkedListInt l12 = { .value = 4, .next = &l13 };
  SinglyLinkedListInt l11 = { .value = 2, .next = &l12 };

  SinglyLinkedListInt l23 = { .value = 4, .next = NULL };
  SinglyLinkedListInt l22 = { .value = 6, .next = &l23 };
  SinglyLinkedListInt l21 = { .value = 5, .next = &l22 };

  SinglyLinkedListInt *result = add_two_numbers(&l11, &l21);

  while (result) {
    printf("%d ", result->value);
    result = result->next;
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with this, but that there are some improvements you could make.

## A Better Abstraction

The way you have it now, a user of this linked list type has to do a bunch of work to create and maintain the list. You could make it a lot easier on a user to define a list type separate from the node type. Something like this:

```
typedef struct IntNode {
    int value;
    struct IntNode *next;
} IntNode;
```

and

```
typedef struct IntList {
    IntNode *head;
    IntNode *tail;
} IntList;
```

What this allows you to do is quickly insert at the head and tail, which are 2 common operations. It also means that a user of this type doesn't have to make all the links between the nodes manually.

You could add a function to create a new empty list, a function to insert an `int` into the list at the tail, and another to remove an `int` from the list. Once you have the creation and insertion functions, you don't need to put memory allocation code into the `add()` function. You would simply create the list at the start of the `add()` function, then as you go through the 2 input lists, generate the new `int` containing the sum, and insert it into the list. It might look something like this:

```
SinglyLinkedListInt *add_two_numbers(SinglyLinkedListInt *l1, SinglyLinkedListInt *l2) {
  SinglyLinkedListInt *result = create_new_list();
  if (result == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  int carry = 0;
  while (l1 || l2 || carry) {
    int a = l1 ? l1->value : 0;
    int b = l2 ? l2->value : 0;
    int value = carry + a + b;

    append(result, value % 10);

    carry = value / 10;
    l1 = l1 ? l1->next : NULL;
    l2 = l2 ? l2->next : NULL;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Here you'd write the `create_new_list()` function and the `append()` function that would add the new value to the end of the list. Now you don't have allocation code in a math function, and you don't need to keep track of the current node and keep incrementing it. (As pointed out by @chux, you will need some way to tell whether `append()` successfully allocated memory or not. I would probably have it return a boolean indicating success or failure and make sure to check it after calling.)

## Memory Management

You are correct that not calling `free()` on something that you've created with `malloc()` is a problem. In the code you currently have, you should be freeing result and every node in the list after you're done using them. Note that that's one more thing a user of this code has to keep track of: some lists are created on the stack and some are created on the heap, and it's even possible that some nodes in the same list could be created in different places and need to be handled differently for freeing them.

If they were always created on the heap, it would simplify using the type by having a `free_list()` function that did it for you. If you used my above suggestion about creating a separate `IntList` type, it might look something like this:

```
void free_list(IntList *list)
{
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    IntNode* current_node = list->head;
    IntNode* next_node = NULL;
    while (current_node != NULL)
    {
        next_node = current_node->next;
        free(current_node);
        current_node = next_node;
    }
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    free(list);
}
```

Then your call sequence becomes:

```
IntList* list = create_new_list();
// ... Add some nodes
list->append(...);
list->append(...);
//... do whatever else with the list
free_list(list);
```

Comment: A 2 member `struct` like `typedef struct IntList {
    IntNode *head;
    IntNode *tail;
} IntList;` is not necessary to add to the head and tail of a LL.   A pointer to the tail (whose `next` member points to the head) is sufficient.

Comment: `void free_list(IntList *list)` should set its members to `NULL` before returning.  `list->head = NULL;`  (and `list->tail = NULL;` if implemented.)  Otherwise,  `free(list)` may be needed here.

Comment: This code checks for allocation error with `if (result == NULL)`, that is good.  Yet does not look for allocation error due to  `append(result, value % 10);`, that is inconsistent.  OP's use of `root` allows for a single check (presently missing) right after the `malloc()` an advantage to OP's header-less LL.

Comment: Regarding only keeping a pointer to `tail` - that seems like the type of thing that will lead to subtle bugs because it's non-obvious, and it only saves 4-8 bytes typically, so not worth it in my opinion. The `struct` with both `head` and `tail` is much clearer. But good points otherwise. I'll make an update shortly.

Comment: An applications may have millions of linked-lists with the majority of them empty - LL are a core building block for many applications.  Having an efficient empty size of 4 vs. 8 is significant.   Concerning bug-ness this answer's first  header & LL approach failed to free memory properly and did not check for out-of-memory in the LL allocation path. Various approaches have their value.

Answer (score 1):

The artificial `root` node gets inaccessible after the return of `root.next`.
One should immediately free it. However better is to not allocate it in the first place.

This is done by having current be an *alias* of either the root list (null), or a `next` field.

```
SinglyLinkedListInt *root = NULL;
SinglyLinkedListInt **current = &root;
...
    *current = next;

    carry = value / 10;
    l1 = l1 ? l1->next : NULL;
    l2 = l2 ? l2->next : NULL;
    current = &(*current)->next;
...
return root;
```

As you see aliasing (altering root or a next field) is a unique property of C, not present in java for instance.

Freeing a list can be done on the entire list, as long as lists are created in their integrally, not single nodes.

```
void freeSinglyLinkedListInt(SinglyLinkedListInt *list) {
    while (list) {
        SinglyLinkedListInt *current = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(current);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
freeSinglyLinkedListInt(list);
list = NULL; // No longer usable.
```

About naming and so on I see no problem; a bit long, but clear. The struct would be a "node", but a struct pointer already a "list." Borrow the convention from other places, I am no longer primarily occupated with C, and
am unsure whether to recommend anything like a typedef.

Comment: OP's `SinglyLinkedListInt root = { .value = 0, .next = NULL };` is not allocated and so should not be free'd.  Only the `root.next` is returned and the fact that `root` goes out of scope is of no consequence.

Comment: @chux that betrays my everydays work is in java.

Answer (score 1):

Code design has problems if `int value` is negative.  After summing, the sum may have some LL nodes with positive values and other with negative ones.  Additional code needed to handle this, including the shrinking of the LL, should there be cancellation.

If code is only designed for positive numbers, then use `unsigned value;`

---

Consider an easier to code, review and maintain allocation idiom:

```
// ptr = malloc(sizeof (type_pointed_to_by_ptr));
ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
```

---

OP's use of a local `root` would benefit with a "only the `.next` member is used" comment.  The use of a temporary "root" makes for efficient code.  Don't give up on this style.

```
SinglyLinkedListInt *add_two_numbers(SinglyLinkedListInt *l1, SinglyLinkedListInt *l2) {
  SinglyLinkedListInt root = { .next = NULL /* Only next member used */};
  SinglyLinkedListInt *current = &root;
```

---

`const` can allow for some optimizations and it also conveys to the caller that the LL are not changed.

```
SinglyLinkedListInt *add_two_numbers(const SinglyLinkedListInt *l1, 
    const SinglyLinkedListInt *l2) {
```

---

OP did not use `restrict` here, which is good, to allow `b = a + a`

```
SinglyLinkedListInt *result = add_two_numbers(&l11, &l11);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a problem:

> ```
> SinglyLinkedListInt *next = malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedListInt));
> next->value = value % 10;
> ```

If `malloc()` returns a null pointer, then accessing `next->value` is **undefined behaviour**.  Always handle all possible return values!

Style point: instead of repeating the type name to compute the size, it's usually safer to use the object as argument:

```
SinglyLinkedListInt *const next = malloc(sizeof *next);
```

(I added `const` to make it more obvious that we never change `next` to point anywhere else.)